# String to FileInputSteam

Tags: java, spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, openshift

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount =
    new FileInputStream("push-manager-app/src/main/resources/serviceAccountKey.json");
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://test1-use.firebaseio.com")
                .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

The above code for `Firebase` connector is working fine. But in `openshift` environment I can't commit `serviceAccountKey.json` in resources as it will be different for different environments. I can get it as `String` from `openshift` configmap in each environment.

For running this block of code I need to convert `String` in `FileInputStream`. I'm not sure how to do it. I have one workaround where I can read `String`, generate file and use it. But I wanted to use the right way. I checked `Firebase` API for other options but it can't even handle `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String json = "xxxxxx";
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: That's what I tried but InputStream doesn't work with GoogleCredential api

Comment: Can you write string to a temp file in the ```openshift ```environment?

Comment: @Pramod is it not this lib? Seems to accept InputStream? https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/index.html?com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html

Comment: sorry, it worked. I think i missed the charset last time. thanks for bringing it in the notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static InputStream getFile() {
    return FireBaseService.class.getResourceAsStream("/dataCred.json");
}
private static final String DATABASE_URL = "DATABASE_URL";

public static void initiainzeSDK() {
    
   try {
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(getFile()))
                .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL)
                .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    // Initialize the default app

    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

make sure ur json file not wrong syntax